# Passing state thru passport-steam (OpenID)

Tags: javascript, passport.js

I am currently using `passport-steam` to authenticate in a feathersjs app...The user is redirected properly and the return_uri is hit w/ their steam info, however, I cannot get the state to pass to steam and back.

I have state set to true on the `new SteamStrategh({...})`

but no matter how deep I look in the returning object, I am not getting it back.

`passport.authenticate('steam', { state: JSON.stringify(state).toString('base64'), })`